# Code Composer Studio Skipping Breakpoints When Compiling with GNU

Tags: c, gnu, msp430, texas-instruments, code-composer

I'm attempting to debug a program in Code Composer Studio compiling with the GNU toolchain rather than the default TI, it's my understanding that CCS by default only places CCS breakpoints which are not recognized by the GDB when working in a CCS project.
My code is inside a CCS project hence my breakpoints are being ignored. I read somewhere that when working inside a C/C++ project the breakpoints placed will be GDB breakpoints but when working inside a C/C++ project it doesn't seem to actually run the code on the microcontroller itself.

I need to be able to debug my code running on the microcontroller itself while also using the GNU compiler toolchain but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check target configuration. What kind of hardware is it ? Does the hardware support hardware breakpoints ? Is the program flashed correctly ? Some hardware support only a limited number of hardware breakpoints. Gnu toolchain should also include "-g" or "--symdebug:dwarf".